# random substitution function for arbitrary Clojure form

Tags: clojure

Given an arbitrary form in a Clojure expression, I would like to design a function that returns a form of the same type signature randomly chosen.

The function, which I'll name rand-form-sub, should behave as follows:

```
(rand-form-sub 2) => 8
(rand-form-sub 'or) => and 
  ;; both and and or obey the same haskellian type signature:
  ;; f :: a -> a -> bool, where as are comparable for equality
(rand-form-sub '+) => - ;; both + and - obey f :: int -> int -> int
```

I suspect that the solution involves 1) limiting the scope of the function to a subset of Clojure (e.g., standard lib) 2) a cond structure at the top-most level 3) an array-map representing semantically valid substitutions.

Finally, I'm aware of a possible limitation in Clojure's lack of type signatures, but I'm willing to compromise to find the best method possible.

**How can I find a form of an equivalent type signature for an arbitrary Clojure form, given that Clojure doesn't have type signatures?**

NOTE: Please feel free to edit to correct any misuse of jargon in my post: I'm not sure if I'm using the term form correctly.

Comment: I'm not sure I can find an actual question here?

Comment: Give me a few minutes, and I'll rephrase the question to be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer, but you might find inspiration in clojure.spec generators:
https://clojure.org/guides/spec#_generators